# FileSystemWatcher Specific Event

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a program that monitors a directory(stage) for any files coming in (Its usually FTP'd) through another service. I have a method to monitor the directory and an event that is triggered when a file comes in but the same method is also triggered when the file is moved to archive.
I want my monitoring method to monitor only when files comes and trigger an event and not when a file moves out of the same directory.

```
 private void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
            _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            _watcher.Path = path;
            _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            _watcher.Changed += FileCreated;
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }

    private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
           //Do some work and move the file received

        }
```

The event is triggered once when the files comes in and once when it being moved. I was filter it to trigger only when the file comes in and not when its moved.

Comment: There is event `OnCreated`, it gets triggered only when file created https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Its does not even trigger an event , when i copy a file to my stage.. We dont create files on the directory they are pushed from another services once processed they are moved to archive directory

Comment: @alangilbi `move` is a change (a rename), not a creation, unless you "move" to a different disk

Comment: @alangilbi the FSW will *drop* events if the event handler takes too long. You should offload any heavy processing to eg a Task and set a big buffer for FSW

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Created` instead of `Changed`.

Because `Changed` observes all changes on files in the path (including creation, deletion)

> Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is changed.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(loadFile);
```

Comment: Yeah I had it has created before, but then it would not even capture any event when the file is FTP'd to my stage.I think there is a difference between a file created in stage to when a file is moved by a service or Ftp'd to my stage.

Comment: Is there something with the NotifyFilter that can be changed..?

Answer (score 0):

I originally suggested that you subscribe to the `Created` event instead of the `Changed` event, but you have mentioned that that event doesn't appear to be fired when your file is created.

I vaguely remember encountering a similar issue myself, and ended up subscribing to the `Changed` event and then checking the `ChangeType` in the event args, as follows:

```
private void MonitorDirectory(string path)
{
    _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    _watcher.Path = path;
    _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    _watcher.Changed += FileCreated;
    _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created || e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed) {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Further information: [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Its does not even trigger an event , when i copy a file to my stage.. We dont create files on the directory they are pushed from another services once processed they are moved to archive directory

Comment: @alangilbi I've updated my answer with a method I've used before when the `Created` event wasn't being fired as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a file is moved and doesn't exist in the folder in your FileCreatedMethod.

```
  private void MonitorDirectory(string path)
    {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        _watcher.Path = path;
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        _watcher.Changed+= FileCreated;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
       if(System.IO.File.Exist(e.FullPath)
        {
       //Do some work and move the file received
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its does not even trigger an event , when i copy a file to my stage.. We dont create files on the directory they are pushed from another services once processed they are moved to archive directory